# WF Persistence - remove old workflows

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

When using Workflow Foundation with persistence there comes a point we want to drop some (or all) workflows out of it which no longer should be persisted/run.

Any script/tool that I can use for this?

Comment: Are these workflows that are still "active" in the sense that they have not completed or terminated?

Comment: @Fredrik yes they are "Active"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard WF tool you can use to do this. The best way is just go into the persistence database through some custom command line tool and remove them. The SqlWorkflowPersistenceService isn't any help because you have to start the WF runtime before you can use it to retrieve workflows and they would also be able to start running.